# Bar magnets side by side, same polarity, attractive force along sides?

Tags: electromagnetism

This shows the magnetic field strength for two bar magnets, the first image with opposite poles facing each other, and the second side by side with same polarity. The magnetic fields are almost identical, does that mean there is attraction for the magnets that are side by side as well (albeit smaller than total repulsive force)?

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2jb2.gif)

[image]

Comment: You need to invest in some magnets of various shapes, a plastic tray and a bag of iron filings...

Comment: as poles repel and in case assumption is true total force there would be much higher, not sure you would get much out that

Comment: iron filing field lines around two bar magnets side by side https://i.imgur.com/bKDCCko.jpg.